# How to change text color when selected in uipickerview?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I want to change the color of the row that the selection of the uipickerview lands on. There is another question like this but the only answer is showing how to make all the text in the uipickerview changed to a certain color. I just want the text when selected in the viewer to appear a different color.

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent: (NSInteger) component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    NSString *rowItem =[thing objectAtIndex:row];
    UILabel *lblRow = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView bounds].size.width, 44.0f];
    [lblRow setTextColor: [UIColor grayColor]];
    [lblRow setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [lblRow setText:rowItem];

    [lblRow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor];

    return lblRow;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using this delegate method instead:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSString *rowItem =[thing objectAtIndex:row];
    UILabel *lblRow = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [pickerView bounds].size.width, 44.0f];
    [lblRow setTextColor: [UIColor grayColor]];
    [lblRow setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
    [lblRow setText:rowItem];

    [lblRow setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: Do you call upon this method because I just implemented this with 4 components and it doesn't work.

Comment: Its a delegate method of the UIPickerViewDelegate protocol. If your view controller is setup to implement this protocol then you can provide an implementation of this method and it will get called when the user selects a row in a component.

Comment: I put a NSLog in and it displays that, but some reason it is not changing the color...

Comment: He miss Add the label to the picker