# Change Color of single, selected Row in UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uipicker

I am developing app in which i am using UIPickerView but now i want to change the color of selected Row text color.
How can i do this ?
I am using this method

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649740/how-to-change-text-color-when-selected-in-uipickerview